Como abro dos ventanas en tkinter?
Estoy intentando que se abra una ventana inicial donde se escoge con 2 botones si se quiere jugar solo o contra un amigo, el problema es que al presionar cualquiera de los botones no se abre correctamente la segunda ventana y pone que no existe la imagen que quiero cargar. Si quito del codigo la ventana inicial y abro directamente la ventana del juego (ajedrez), no hay ningun problema al cargar las imagenes y funciona correctamente.
Como puedo hacer para que al presionar los botones se cierre la ventana inicial y se abra correctamente la pantalla del juego?
 import tkinter as tk
 from tkinter import messagebox

 class Tablero:
 def __init__(self,root,modo):#modo:   0 = IA      1 = Con amigo

     self.state=Juego()
     self.turno = 'Blanc'
     self.modo = modo
     print(self.modo)

     self.ruta_imagenes = "C:/Users/AleixZafraGámez/Desktop/TdR/Ajedrez/Imagenes/"
     self.imagenes = {}
     self.cargarImagenes()
     self.colorFondo = '#302E2B'

     self.ventana = root
     self.ventana.title('Escacs')
     self.ventana.config(bg=self.colorFondo)
     self.ventana.state('zoomed')

     self.frameBlanco = tk.Frame(self.ventana,height=50,bg=self.colorFondo).pack()

     self.frameTurno = tk.Frame(self.ventana,height=50,width=400,bg='#76C25C',bd=5,relief=tk.RIDGE)
     self.frameTurno.pack()
     self.frameTablero = tk.Frame(self.ventana,height=400,width=400,bg='#5D9948',bd=20,relief=tk.RAISED)
     self.frameTablero.pack()


#Label Turno
     self.labelTurno = tk.Label(self.frameTurno, text=f'Torn de: {self.turno}',font=('Comic Sans MS',13),bg='#76C25C')
     self.labelTurno.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=50)

#Label Undo
     self.labelUndo = tk.Button(self.frameTurno, text='UNDO',font=('Comic Sans MS',10),command= lambda: self.state.undo()).grid(row=0,column=1,padx=50,pady=5)

#Botones
     self.b00 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='white',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[0][0]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(0,0)).grid(row=0,column=0)
     self.b01 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='gray',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[0][1]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(0,1)).grid(row=0,column=1)
     self.b02 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='white',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[0][2]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(0,2)).grid(row=0,column=2)
     self.b03 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='gray',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[0][3]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(0,3)).grid(row=0,column=3)
     self.b04 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='white',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[0][4]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(0,4)).grid(row=0,column=4)
     self.b05 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='gray',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[0][5]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(0,5)).grid(row=0,column=5)
     self.b06 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='white',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[0][6]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(0,6)).grid(row=0,column=6)
     self.b07 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='gray',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[0][7]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(0,7)).grid(row=0,column=7)
     
     self.b10 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='gray',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[1][0]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(1,0)).grid(row=1,column=0)
     self.b11 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='white',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[1][1]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(1,1)).grid(row=1,column=1)
     self.b12 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='gray',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[1][2]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(1,2)).grid(row=1,column=2)
     self.b13 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='white',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[1][3]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(1,3)).grid(row=1,column=3)
     self.b14 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='gray',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[1][4]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(1,4)).grid(row=1,column=4)
     self.b15 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='white',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[1][5]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(1,5)).grid(row=1,column=5)
     self.b16 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='gray',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[1][6]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(1,6)).grid(row=1,column=6)
     self.b17 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='white',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[1][7]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(1,7)).grid(row=1,column=7)
     
     self.b20 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='white',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[2][0]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(2,0)).grid(row=2,column=0)
     self.b21 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='gray',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[2][1]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(2,1)).grid(row=2,column=1)
     self.b22 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='white',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[2][2]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(2,2)).grid(row=2,column=2)
     self.b23 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='gray',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[2][3]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(2,3)).grid(row=2,column=3)
     self.b24 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='white',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[2][4]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(2,4)).grid(row=2,column=4)
     self.b25 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='gray',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[2][5]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(2,5)).grid(row=2,column=5)
     self.b26 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='white',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[2][6]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(2,6)).grid(row=2,column=6)
     self.b27 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='gray',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[2][7]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(2,7)).grid(row=2,column=7)
     
     self.b30 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='gray',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[3][0]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(3,0)).grid(row=3,column=0)
     self.b31 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='white',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[3][1]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(3,1)).grid(row=3,column=1)
     self.b32 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='gray',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[3][2]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(3,2)).grid(row=3,column=2)
     self.b33 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='white',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[3][3]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(3,3)).grid(row=3,column=3)
     self.b34 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='gray',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[3][4]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(3,4)).grid(row=3,column=4)
     self.b35 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='white',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[3][5]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(3,5)).grid(row=3,column=5)
     self.b36 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='gray',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[3][6]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(3,6)).grid(row=3,column=6)
     self.b37 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='white',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[3][7]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(3,7)).grid(row=3,column=7)
     
     self.b40 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='white',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[4][0]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(4,0)).grid(row=4,column=0)
     self.b41 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='gray',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[4][1]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(4,1)).grid(row=4,column=1)
     self.b42 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='white',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[4][2]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(4,2)).grid(row=4,column=2)
     self.b43 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='gray',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[4][3]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(4,3)).grid(row=4,column=3)
     self.b44 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='white',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[4][4]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(4,4)).grid(row=4,column=4)
     self.b45 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='gray',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[4][5]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(4,5)).grid(row=4,column=5)
     self.b46 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='white',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[4][6]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(4,6)).grid(row=4,column=6)
     self.b47 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='gray',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[4][7]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(4,7)).grid(row=4,column=7)
     
     self.b50 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='gray',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[5][0]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(5,0)).grid(row=5,column=0)
     self.b51 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='white',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[5][1]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(5,1)).grid(row=5,column=1)
     self.b52 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='gray',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[5][2]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(5,2)).grid(row=5,column=2)
     self.b53 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='white',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[5][3]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(5,3)).grid(row=5,column=3)
     self.b54 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='gray',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[5][4]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(5,4)).grid(row=5,column=4)
     self.b55 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='white',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[5][5]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(5,5)).grid(row=5,column=5)
     self.b56 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='gray',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[5][6]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(5,6)).grid(row=5,column=6)
     self.b57 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='white',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[5][7]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(5,7)).grid(row=5,column=7)
     
     self.b60 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='white',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[6][0]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(6,0)).grid(row=6,column=0)
     self.b61 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='gray',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[6][1]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(6,1)).grid(row=6,column=1)
     self.b62 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='white',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[6][2]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(6,2)).grid(row=6,column=2)
     self.b63 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='gray',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[6][3]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(6,3)).grid(row=6,column=3)
     self.b64 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='white',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[6][4]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(6,4)).grid(row=6,column=4)
     self.b65 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='gray',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[6][5]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(6,5)).grid(row=6,column=5)
     self.b66 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='white',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[6][6]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(6,6)).grid(row=6,column=6)
     self.b67 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='gray',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[6][7]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(6,7)).grid(row=6,column=7)
     
     self.b70 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='gray',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[7][0]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(7,0)).grid(row=7,column=0)
     self.b71 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='white',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[7][1]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(7,1)).grid(row=7,column=1)
     self.b72 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='gray',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[7][2]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(7,2)).grid(row=7,column=2)
     self.b73 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='white',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[7][3]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(7,3)).grid(row=7,column=3)
     self.b74 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='gray',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[7][4]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(7,4)).grid(row=7,column=4)
     self.b75 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='white',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[7][5]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(7,5)).grid(row=7,column=5)
     self.b76 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='gray',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[7][6]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(7,6)).grid(row=7,column=6)
     self.b77 = tk.Button(self.frameTablero,height=50,width=50,bg='white',relief=tk.RAISED,bd=3,image=self.imagenes[self.state.tablero[7][7]], command= lambda: self.state.casillaSeleccionada(7,7)).grid(row=7,column=7)

def crearJuego(modoAjedrez):
 global juego
 root=tk.Tk()
 juego=Tablero(root,modoAjedrez)
 root.mainloop()


def sortir():
 ventanaInicial.quit()

colorFondo = '#302E2B'
colorLetras = '#FFFFFF'
ventanaInicial = tk.Tk()
ventanaInicial.title('Escacs')
ventanaInicial.state('zoomed')
ventanaInicial.config(bg=colorFondo)

frameVacio = tk.Frame(ventanaInicial,height=100,bg=colorFondo)
frameVacio.pack()
frameTitulo = tk.Frame(ventanaInicial,width=400,height=80,bg=colorFondo)
frameTitulo.pack()
titulo = tk.Label(frameTitulo,text='ESCACS',font=('Comic Sans MS',50),bg=colorFondo,fg=colorLetras)
titulo.pack(pady=20)

framePregunta = tk.Frame(ventanaInicial,width=400,height=80,bg=colorFondo)
framePregunta.pack()
pregunta = tk.Label(framePregunta,text='Vols jugar contra la IA o contra un amic?',font=('Montserrat',20),bg=colorFondo,fg=colorLetras)
pregunta.pack(pady=20)

frameBotones = tk.Frame(ventanaInicial,width=400,height=80,bg=colorFondo)
frameBotones.pack()
botonIA = tk.Button(frameBotones,text='Jugar contra la IA',font=('Montserrat',15),bg='#5D9948',bd=5,relief=tk.RAISED,activebackground='#76C25C',command= lambda: crearJuego(0))
botonIA.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=20,pady=30)
botonAmic = tk.Button(frameBotones,text='Jugar contra un amic',font=('Montserrat',15),bg='#5D9948',bd=5,relief=tk.RAISED,activebackground='#76C25C',command= lambda: crearJuego(1))
botonAmic.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=20,pady=30)

frameSortir = tk.Frame(ventanaInicial,width=400,height=80,bg=colorFondo)
frameSortir.pack()
botonSortir = tk.Button(frameSortir,text='Sortir',command= lambda: sortir(),font=('Montserrat',15),bg='#5D9948',bd=5,relief=tk.RAISED,activebackground='#76C25C').pack()

ventanaInicial.mainloop()



Menos mal que solo tienes 77 celdas en el tablero y no varios miles... Un loop te vendría bien, en vez de repetir una y otra vez absolutamente el mismo código! Por otro lado, veo inconsistencias en el sangrado de tu código. Especialmente en python es muy MUY importante mantener un sangrado idéntico en todas partes. Es decir, si usas 4 espacios para indicar un bloque, deberías usar siempre 4, no de repente cambiar a uno o dos... por favor, consistencia!

Nunca uses más de una instancia de tkinter.Tk por proceso, en vez de eso usa tkinter.Toplevel para crear cuantas ventanas secundarias quieras y oculta la principal de ser necesario. El error de "la imagen no existe" es una consecuencia de esto y está tambén explicado en mi respuesta a esta otra pregunta: Misma imagen en diferentes ventanas, Python, Tkinter, "image "pyimage2" doesn't exist" y que creo que es una buena candidata a duplicado. Mirala a ver si te aclara el problema y comenta si tienes alguna duda.

El sangrado está bien, pero lo he copiado un poco mal en el mensaje. Gracias, lo voy a intentar como dices.
